# Mass Find and Replace control characters in SQL

Tags: mysql, replace, ascii, control-characters

ASCII control characters are finding their way in to databases I maintain at a semi-frequent basis. While I plan to implement the means to prevent them from being `INSERT`ed  in to SQL I have to first deal with characters *already* present in the database *first*.

For starters I know that it's possible to do a **find and replace** using SQL...

```
UPDATE [table_name] 
SET [field_name]=REPLACE([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

PHP allows you to use an array to replace multiple items with something else...

```
$result = str_ireplace(array('1','2','3','4','5'),'0',$my_string);
```

So instead of lazy SQL queries in loops is there a way we can contruct an SQL query to replace multiple ASCII control characters?

Also very important is **how** we replace those control characters (e.g. as dec, oct, hex)?

Also I've read that **carriage return** is part of the control characters 0~31 so obviously we don't want to remove those to make sure line-breaks are retained unless I'm missing something on that?

Here is a reference page I'm going by right now...

http://www.ascii-code.com/

---

I code XHTML as application/xhtml+xml and tested the following as **example1.xhtml** and open EXPLICITLY in **Firefox** with **NO BYTE ORDER MARK (BOM)**...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<p>&#000;&#001;&#002;&#003;&#004;&#005;&#006;&#007;&#008;&#009;
&#010;&#011;&#012;&#013;&#014;&#015;&#016;&#017;&#018;&#019;
&#020;&#021;&#022;&#023;&#024;&#025;&#026;&#027;&#028;&#029;
&#030;&#031;</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The following are the only characters that can be used without creating malformed XML, save as **example2.xhtml** and open EXPLICITLY in **Firefox** with **NO BYTE ORDER MARK (BOM)**...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<p>&#009;&#010;&#013;</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Those working characters that we do *not* want to strip in SQL are...

- 09 - Horizontal Tab
- 10 - Line Feed
- 13 - Carriage Return

Comment: So you only want to remove *some* control characters, but not others?  Which are the characters that you *do* want to remove (and why)?  MySQL does not have any native method of performing operations of this sort, although there are UDFs out there (such as the `PREG_REPLACE()` function provided by the [`lib_mysqludf_preg`](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) library) that you can use to do the trick.

Comment: @eggyal I've done a bit of testing and have updated which characters need to be replaced to keep XML from being malformed when it is received from SQL.

Comment: If it's a case of not rendering invalid XML, you should probably pass the database results through an escaping function before outputting as XML.  Otherwise the XML might also be broken by non-control (i.e. "printing" characters) such as `<` or `&`.

Comment: @eggyal Using `htmlspecialchars()` is effective to an extent. While I'm open to to utilizing other functions or a combination instead the goal is to simply clean out the entire table.

Comment: The "control" characters that you have identified as being invalid are indeed not supported by XML 1.0, but they *are* valid in XML 1.1.  Out of interest, why are you using XHTML 1.1 in XML 1.0?

Comment: To obtain an XML 1.0 compliant string, you can specify appropriate flags to the escaping function - e.g. `htmlentities($str, ENT_XML1 | ENT_DISALLOWED)`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for starters though does not necessarily do it in mass...

```
UPDATE a_log SET useragent=replace(useragent,char(4),'');
UPDATE a_log SET useragent=replace(useragent,char(5),'');
```

What I did was first copy the XML parsing error from Firefox. The Windows 7 clipboard *does* properly retain the ASCII control characters while doing a copy and paste. Then I pasted the offending text in to the form at this website...

http://www.asciivalue.com/

Finding the line I used the **DEC** and **OCT** (their column values matched) to reference the characters on this site...

http://www.ascii-code.com/

...and after a little research I was able to throw together a couple lines to clean out the offending characters that ended up malforming my XML.

I will still accept a better answer as the point is to to more of a dragnet styled fix. Additionally I actively admit this is unfortunately more of a *reactionary* stance to the problem to which I still must create, test and implement measures to *prevent* ASCII control characters from being inserted in to MySQL to begin with; I am therefore still looking for a well-written way to *prevent* this problem.

Should someone ask the same question and come across it they have *some* effective means of resolving the problem in the very least.